# Почему такая большая разница в точности при применении критерия Джини и энтропии?

Tags: python, алгоритм, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, классификация

Всем привет.
Продолжаю потихоньку изучать ML и добрался до известного дата-сета '[Wine](https://archive.%20ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/wine)'. И упёрся в следующий момент: если я использую энтропию в качестве критерия вместо критерия Джини, то точность падает на 4-10%.
На примере кода

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix
dataset = load_wine()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataset.data, dataset.target, test_size=0.322, random_state = 42)
dt_wine = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
dt_wine = dt_wine.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = dt_wine.predict(X_test)
test_accuracy= metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print("Accuracy: ", '%.2f'% (test_accuracy*100),"%")
```

Accuracy:  94.83 %
но если запускаю

```
dt_wine = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')
```

то Accuracy 84.48

Я пробовал играть с данными, но всё равно энтропия показывает результаты хуже чем Джинни.
Это энтропия не подходит к данному дата сету или она действительно хуже чем критерий Джинни в большинстве вариантов? Или это я что-то неправильно сделал (например точность посчитал)? Теорию читал и не нашёл никаких предпосылок для столь больших отличий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите воспроизводимые результаты обучения модели, то всегда используйте параметр `random_state`, иначе вы можете получить разные результаты на абсолютно тех же датасетах.

Пример - два раза запускаем один и тот же код (одни и те же датасеты):

```
In [29]: %paste
dt_wine = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
dt_wine = dt_wine.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = dt_wine.predict(X_test)
test_accuracy= metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print("Accuracy: ", '%.2f'% (test_accuracy*100),"%")

## -- End pasted text --
Accuracy:  96.55 %

In [30]: %paste
dt_wine = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
dt_wine = dt_wine.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = dt_wine.predict(X_test)
test_accuracy= metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print("Accuracy: ", '%.2f'% (test_accuracy*100),"%")

## -- End pasted text --
Accuracy:  94.83 %
```

Точность предсказаний уменьшилась во втором случае. Для того, чтобы этого избежать надо использовать параметр `random_state`:

---

По поводу выбора критерия - если бы один критерий был бы **всегда** лучше другого, то наверное не имело бы смысла оставлять тот критерий, который всегда дает худший результат. ;)

Критерий является одним их гиперпараметров модели, который можно и нужно настраивать ([GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), [RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV), [hyperopt](https://hyperopt.github.io/hyperopt/), etc.)

Если вы используете алгоритмы, основанные на деревьях решений, то я бы советовал использовать [Decision Tree Ensembles алгоритмы](https://towardsdatascience.com/decision-tree-ensembles-bagging-and-boosting-266a8ba60fd9#:~:text=Ensemble%20methods%2C%20which%20combines%20several,to%20form%20a%20strong%20learner.) - они гораздо устойчивее к переобучению и почти всегда дают лучшие результаты, по сравнению с использованием единичных деревьев.

Пример для ваших данных:

```
In [52]: from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

In [53]: rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=123)

In [54]: rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
Out[54]:
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None,
                       criterion='gini', max_depth=None, max_features='auto',
                       max_leaf_nodes=None, max_samples=None,
                       min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                       min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                       min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=100,
                       n_jobs=None, oob_score=False, random_state=123,
                       verbose=0, warm_start=False)

In [55]: y_pred2 = rf.predict(X_test)

In [56]: metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred2)
Out[56]: 1.0
```

Comment: Спасибо, про random_state я забыл совсем.
Про критерии понял.
До  Decision Tree Ensembles я ещё не дочитал, доберусь скорее-всего к концу месяца до них.